# Django Nested Serializer Field - Empty OrderedDict

Tags: django, django-serializer

I'm currently having an issue with updating a nested serializer field, the dict value provided is being thrown away and mapped to an empty dict on the code side

Serializer:

```
class OrganizationSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, BaseSecuritySerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ("id", "name")
        depth = 0

class UsersSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, BaseSecuritySerializer):
    organizations = OrganizationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 0

    def update(self, instance: ReportSchedule, validated_data):
        print("validated_data:", validated_data)
        ...
```

REST Request:
METHOD: Patch

```
{
    "organizations": [{"id": 10}]
}
```

Outcome of print statement

```
validated_data: {'organizations': [OrderedDict()]}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am having the same issue where the nested serializer data is converting to a list of OrderedDict's but they are all empty.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the 'id' field in OrganizationSerializer is read_only, you can check it yourself in python manage.py shell

```
test = OrganizationSerializer()
print(repr(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tempresdisk's method above, the serializer should look like this

```
OrganizationSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)  
    ...
```

Overriding that field in the serializer and removing the `read_only=True` should do the trick.

```
class OrganizationSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin, BaseSecuritySerializer):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID')

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ("id", "name")
        depth = 0
```